# How to know which ZSH configuration framework is installed?

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh, prezto

I'm trying to automate installing a ZSH plugin depending on which configuration framework the user is running (For example - prezto or oh-my-zsh) since the install location of the plugin changes with the change in config framework.

For example, for oh-my-zsh the plugins must be installed in `~/.oh-my-zsh/custom/plugins` folder whereas in prezto they must be installed in the `~/.prezto/modules` folder.

Is there a way I could determine the configuration framework or a workaround to install the plugin in both these cases? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of the framework in use, the location of the plugins is configurable by the user, so detecting a framework only lets you predict the *default* location of the plugin directory, not the directory actually in use.

Just use an environment variable like `PLUGINDIR` in your installer, and let the user be responsible for setting its value to `~/.oh-my-zsh/custom/plugins` or `~/.prezto/modules` or `~/.config/zsh/oh-my-zsh-plugs`, etc., as appropriate.